# Modular Programming in C++ for OS kernel

Tags: c++, linux, module, kernel

I am working on developing an operating kernel from the scratch. I set the development environment on Linux. After all of the Low Level Programming in Assembly language, now i am working in C++. I have managed the task in different modules. 
There is a problem to me. I will expalin the generic form of my problem.
i have created three files in a in the same directory.

```
1) main.cpp
2) myclass.h
3) myclass.cpp



// main.cpp


        #include<iostream>
        #include"myclass.h"
        using namespace std;
        int main()
        {
            myclass a;
            return 0;
        }

  //myclass.h

#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class myclass
{
public:
    myclass();

};

#endif
```

// myclass.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"myclass.h"
using namespace std;
myclass :: myclass()
{

    cout<<"Constructer";
}
```

when i compile **main.cpp** it shows:

> /tmp/ccm50K0J.o: In function `main':
>   main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to`myclass::myclass()'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

But when i put the function definition in the header file it works.
Thanks in Advance ..............

Comment: How are you compiling it? With a makefile? What are the contents of that makefile?

Comment: g++ main.cpp -o main.out

Comment: You should first do `g++ -c myclass.cpp -o myclass.o`, then you can compile main while asking it to link`myclass.o` a la  `g++ main.cpp -o main.out myclass.o`.

Comment: Thanks brother it worked like a charm.................. thank you